# Sum of geometric progression

Tags: sequences-and-series, geometric-progressions

Given a geometric sequence whose sum of the first ten terms is 4, and whose sum
from the 11th to the 30th term is 48. Find the sum the 31st to the 60th term.

Answer (score 2):

We may write the two conditions as $$\begin{align}
\frac{a}{r-1}(r^{10}-1) &=4,\;\; \text{and}\\
\frac{a r^{10}}{r-1}(r^{20}-1) &=48.
\end{align}
$$
Dividing the second equation by the first yields$$
r^{10}(r^{10}+1) = 12.
$$
We let $x = r^{10}$ and solve $x(x+1)=12$ to find that $r^{10} = 3$ or $-4$.  Geometric progressions are usually defined as real sequences, so we will assume $r^{10} = 3$.  One could proceed with the $-4$ case in the same way.

Substituting $r^{10} = 3$ into the first equation above yields$$
\frac{a}{r-1} = 2.$$
Therefore the sum of the $31^\mathrm{th}$ through $60^\mathrm{th}$ terms is $$
\frac{a r^{30}}{r-1}(r^{30}-1) = 2 \cdot 3^3 \cdot (3^3 - 1) = 1404.$$

Comment: how do you know in the first place the r is < 1 ?

Comment: I don't know whether it is or not initially, but it doesn't matter.  Although I may have written the sum as $a/(r-1) \cdot (r^{10}-1)$ if I knew $r > 1$, it equals the same thing as the way I wrote it.

Comment: r is only required, $r < 1$ in the context of an infinite series.  The terms in question are finite in number.  The only requirement is $r\neq 1$.   The sum of the sequence formula still applies.

Comment: Actually, I'm going to rewrite it to use $r-1$ etc. instead of $1-r$.  It's cleaner that way for finite series with $r>1$.  The $1-r$ can make one think of infinite series, which is distracting.